# 2D Array with JOINED tables

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm using join to query data from two tables. For each a_id I need to get the associated image_id, filter those image_id results so only the first one remains, and finally output the results into an li. I think my query is good but I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around how to get the image_id for each a_id and to output that to my li. This code returns some results but they are not what I'm looking for.

```
<?php
echo '<ul>';
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * from artists left join images on artists.a_id = images.image_id where artists.display_works = '1' and artists.active = '1' order by artists.project_year desc, artists.fullname desc");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $data['a_id']['image_id']=$row->a_id;

    foreach($data as $id=>$images) {
            $totalimages=1;
            $addstyle = "";
            $art_id = $data['a_id'];
            $img_id = $data['image_id'];

            foreach($images as $val){

                    if($totalimages > 1){ $addstyle = 'style="display:none;"'; }
                    else {
                    $myimagename = "http://artists/$art_id/images/$img_id" .  "_large.jpg";
                    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("$myimagename");
                    $myimagename = "http://artists/resize.php/$art_id/images/$img_id" . "_large.jpg?resize(157x2000)";

                    if($row["layout"] == "vert"){$pl = "_vertical";}else if($row["layout"] == "website"){$pl = "-s";}else if($row["layout"] == "video"){$pl = "_video";}else{$pl = "_horizontal";}
                    echo "<li class='thumbnail_container' $addstyle> <a class='thumbnail' href=\"../works$pl.php?a_id=" . $row["a_id"] . "\"><span><img src=\"$myimagename\" /></span>\n</a></li>\n";
                    }

                    $totalimages++;
        }
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Well, I've modified the code a bit and it's working but for some reason I am getting an extra thumbnail after the first image with no image url or link url. I think it may have something to do with my method for checking for duplicate a_ids:

```
<?php
echo '<ul>';
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * from artists left join images on artists.a_id = images.a_id where artists.display_works = '1' and artists.active = '1' order by artists.project_year desc, artists.fullname desc, images.position asc");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $check = $row['a_id'];
    if (in_array($check, $a_ids)) {end;}
    else { 
    $a_id=$row['a_id'];
    $a_ids[] = $a_id;
    $image_id=$row['image_id'];

    $myimagename = "http://artists/$a_id/images/$image_id" .  "_large.jpg";
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("$myimagename");
    $myimagename = "http://artists/resize.php/$a_id/images/$image_id" . "_large.jpg?resize(157x2000)";

    if($row["layout"] == "vert"){$pl = "_vertical";}else if($row["layout"] == "website"){$pl = "-s";}else   if($row["layout"] == "video"){$pl = "_video";}else{$pl = "_horizontal";}
        echo "<li class='thumbnail_container' $addstyle> <a class='thumbnail' href=\"../works$pl.php?a_id=" . $row["a_id"] . "\"><span><img src=\"$myimagename\" /></span>\n</a></li>\n";
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Why are you processing the individual row results INSIDE the fetch loop? The full db results wouldn't be available yet, so whatever this filtering is supposed to can't work properly.

Comment: Where should I move it? More importantly is it correct?

Comment: Move it outside of while() loop. As for correct, no idea. I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish. as it stands now, you fetch a row of data from the DB, then loop over all the things you've fetched so far. Then you fetch another row, loop over everythign again, etc... e.g. you're being a [Schlemiel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm)

Comment: Well, I stated above the code what I was trying to do. Thanks for the insult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I ended up using. What was really making this difficult for me is that I wasn't grasping two concepts.

The first was JOIN. I didn't understand how it was merging the two tables. After reading some more about it I now know that ON is more appropriate when joining columns of different names but what I really wanted was to JOIN both tables by their a_id columns. Even though I've left the ON and have made both column names the same I should look into using the keyword USING as it is specifically used for columns of the same name.

The second concept I was having difficulty understanding was how to get all the info I wanted from the new joined table. I didn't know that using mysql_fetch_array with a while loop would go through each row and get all the data from every column. Once I understood this though it was easy enough to go through each row and get the image_id and a_id.

My final code:

```
<?php
echo '<ul>';
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * from artists left join images on artists.a_id = images.a_id where artists.display_works = '1' and artists.active = '1' order by artists.project_year desc, artists.fullname desc, images.position asc");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $check = $row['a_id'];
    if (!in_array($check, $a_ids) && $check !='') {
    $a_id = $row['a_id'];
    $a_ids[] = $a_id;
    $image_id = $row['image_id'];

    $myimagename = "http://artists/$a_id/images/$image_id" .  "_large.jpg";
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("$myimagename");
    $myimagename = "http://artists/resize.php/$a_id/images/$image_id" . "_large.jpg?resize(157x2000)";

    if($row["layout"] == "vert"){$pl = "_vertical";}else if($row["layout"] == "website"){$pl = "-s";}else   if($row["layout"] == "video"){$pl = "_video";}else{$pl = "_horizontal";}
        echo "<li class='thumbnail_container' $addstyle> <a class='thumbnail' href=\"../works$pl.php?a_id=" . $row["a_id"] . "\"><span><img src=\"$myimagename\" /></span>\n</a></li>\n";
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```